# java.lang.NullPointerException while Retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the picture of  my data in Firebase:

[image: 1]

So am trying to Retrieve `DoctorsName` and `Email` in the Recyclerview when when they are two doctors in the Item List of the recyclerView. But i don't know how to use a `get()` method to retrieve them in my Recycleriew. 
This is the Error I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

Below is my `MainActiviy.java`.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button but;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public List<ModelClass> movies_;
    public Context c;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public DatabaseReference mMovieRef ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        movies_ = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();

        recyclerView =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://askdoctor-546bf.firebaseio.com/Doctors");
       //  mMovieRef = mRef.child("Doctors");


        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




    }



    public void LoadData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot singlesnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String taskTitle =singlesnapshot.getValue(String.class);


            movies_.add(new ModelClass(taskTitle));

            adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, movies_);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        }

    }

}
```

And this is my `Adapter` Class.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by HUZY_KAMZ on 9/16/2016.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {


  protected   Context c;
    List<ModelClass> movies;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

   StorageReference url =storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com/");

    private List<ModelClass> itemList = null;


    public MyAdapter(Context c, List<ModelClass> movies) {
        this.c = c;
        this.movies = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_activity,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  ModelClass feedItems = itemList.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(movies.get(position).getName());
        holder.email_txt.setText(movies.get(position).getEmail());
      // PicassoClient.downloadImage(c,movies.get(position).getUrl(),holder.img);
        //Download image using picasso library
        Picasso.with(c).load(url+ feedItems.getName())
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                resize(120, 50)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.img);




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder

final  ModelClass feedItems = **itemList.get(position);**

**itemList is null** and you try to get something from a null list, so that's why you get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: I think you never use that List so you could simply remove that line, also remove it from the top where you initialize it as Null. The list named "movies" is the right list to use because that list you use when you create your adapter.

Comment: I tried that , but still the same eror @Tony , I think the issue is about the syntax which retrieves that kind of data from Firebase did you check my picture i uploaded . So if you know it please help me.

Comment: have you tried to Log the result of the snapshot? check first if you get the correct values you want before we check how we will set them to a text